# Write output text data into a CSV or excel file as a table

Tags: python, output

I have a programme that outputs results into a .csv file.

However, the results are structured as text one below the other.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9nyc.png): [image: Original output saved as a .csv file]
However, I would need this to be in this format-

[image: Wanted output as a table with columns]

Snippet of my code-

```
PathDicom = "./Images/cases/TCGA-G3-A3CK/01-03-2005-CT CHEST ABDOMEN  PELVIS ENHANCED-BODY-48980/"


ListFold = []; # Create an empty list for folder names

# Make a list of series names (i.e. Folder names) - ListFold
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(PathDicom):
    for filename in subdirList:
        ListFold.append(os.path.join(dirName,filename))


lstFilesDCM = []  # create an empty list

with open ('results_NOISE_duke_new.csv','a+') as f:

    for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(ListFold[0]):

        CTSeriesPath = ListFold[0]
        print("Exam_name:", PathDicom, file=f)
        IQ = CTPatientImageNoise(CTSeriesPath)
        ct_series_noise = {}
        ct_series_noise['Noise'] = IQ.forDatabase['AverageGlobalNoiseIndex']

        print("Series_name:",CTSeriesPath, file=f) # This is the series name
        print("Series_Noise_value:", ct_series_noise['Noise'], file=f)


        for filename in fileList:
                lstFilesDCM.append(os.path.join(dirName,filename))



                RefDs = pydicom.dcmread(lstFilesDCM[0])
                #print("Exam_name:", PathDicom, file=f)
                print("Manufacturer:", RefDs.Manufacturer, file=f)
                print("iMAGE tYPE:", RefDs.ImageType, file=f)
                print("Slice Thickness:", RefDs.SliceThickness, file=f)
                print("Filter Type:", RefDs.FilterType, file=f)
                #print("Convolution Kernel:", RefDs.ConvolutionKernel, file=f)
                print("AccessionNumber:", RefDs.AccessionNumber, file=f)
                print("StudyDescription:", RefDs.StudyDescription, file=f)

                f.write('\n')



                break #
```

***UPDATE*** - 
I have edited as Alfonso suggested in his answer - use pandas -got the answer!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys
import pydicom # Importing DICOM package 
import csv
import os,string
import pandas as pd


from pyctpatientimagenoise import CTPatientImageNoise
PathDicom = "F:/PythonExample/Images/testduke/TCGA-DD-A11C/05-27-1999-Abdomen120LiverBiPhase Adult-61415"

Examname = []
ImageType=[]
Manufacturer = []
Series_name = []
Series_Noise =[]
Slice_thickness = []
Filter_type = []
Accessnum = []
StudyDesc = []
CTSeriesPath = []

# This is a list of all the series (organised as Folders) in the exam
ListFold = []; # Create an empty list for folder names

# Make a list of series names (i.e. Folder names) - ListFold
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(PathDicom):
    for filename in subdirList:
        ListFold.append(os.path.join(dirName,filename))

lstFilesDCM = []  # create an empty list




for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(ListFold[0]): 

        CTSeriesPath = ListFold[0]
        Examname.append(PathDicom)
        IQ = CTPatientImageNoise(CTSeriesPath)
        ct_series_noise = {}
        ct_series_noise['Noise'] = IQ.forDatabase['AverageGlobalNoiseIndex']

        Series_name.append(CTSeriesPath) # This is the series name
        Series_Noise.append(ct_series_noise['Noise'])


        for filename in fileList:
                lstFilesDCM.append(os.path.join(dirName,filename))


                 # Get 1ST SLICE INFO 
                RefDs = pydicom.dcmread(lstFilesDCM[0])
                #print("Exam_name:", PathDicom, file=f)
                Manufacturer.append(RefDs.Manufacturer)
                ImageType.append(RefDs.ImageType)
                Slice_thickness.append(RefDs.SliceThickness)
                Filter_type.append(RefDs.FilterType)
                #print("Convolution Kernel:", RefDs.ConvolutionKernel, file=f)
                Accessnum.append(RefDs.AccessionNumber)
                StudyDesc.append(RefDs.StudyDescription)
                #print("Irradiation Event UID:", RefDs.IrradiationEventUID, file=f)

                break      




for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(ListFold[1]): 

        CTSeriesPath = ListFold[1]
        Examname.append(PathDicom)
        IQ = CTPatientImageNoise(CTSeriesPath)
        ct_series_noise = {}
        ct_series_noise['Noise'] = IQ.forDatabase['AverageGlobalNoiseIndex']

        Series_name.append(CTSeriesPath) # This is the series name
        Series_Noise.append(ct_series_noise['Noise'])


        for filename in fileList:
                lstFilesDCM.append(os.path.join(dirName,filename))


                 # Get 1ST SLICE INFO 
                RefDs = pydicom.dcmread(lstFilesDCM[1])
                #print("Exam_name:", PathDicom, file=f)
                Manufacturer.append(RefDs.Manufacturer)
                ImageType.append(RefDs.ImageType)
                Slice_thickness.append(RefDs.SliceThickness)
                Filter_type.append(RefDs.FilterType)
                #print("Convolution Kernel:", RefDs.ConvolutionKernel, file=f)
                Accessnum.append(RefDs.AccessionNumber)
                StudyDesc.append(RefDs.StudyDescription)
                #print("Irradiation Event UID:", RefDs.IrradiationEventUID, file=f)

                break 

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(Examname, Manufacturer, ImageType, Series_name,Series_Noise,Slice_thickness,Filter_type,Accessnum,StudyDesc )), columns =["Exam","Manufacturer", "iMAGE tYPE", "Series", "Noise", "Slice Thickness", "Filter Type", "Accession Num", "Study Desc"])

df.to_csv("F:/PythonExample/testdel.csv")
```

I have edited my original code to include the solution that worked best with least amount of re-coding.

Comment: Hi, python comes with a csv writer module. please google for that.

Comment: I am new to python. Could you please share a code piece? I have come across PrettyTable via google

Comment: use module `csv` or `pandas.to_csv()` instead of using  standard `write()` and `print()`.  You have to first write only headers (separated by `,`), later `'\n'` and later only values (separated by `,`) - and `cvs` module will care of `,`

Comment: Please show an example

Comment: _Could you please share a code piece?_, _Please show an example_ You won't learn anything if others do all the work for you, I would recommend reading the csv docs.

Comment: I have copied and pasted my code in the question. I have been trying many codes..so unsure what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using pandas to make a dataframe and then saving it to csv?

Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is difficult to give a full answer but I will try.

First you create a list for each desired column

```
Manufacturer_list = []
image_list = []
...
```

and then, in the for loop, replace the `print` statements by `append`

```
Manufacturer_list.append(RefDs.Manufacturer)
image_list.append(RefDs.ImageType)
...
```

Finally you create a dataframe with pandas. [More info here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-pandas-dataframe-from-lists/)

```
# import pandas as pd 
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(Manufacturer_list, image_list, ...)), 
               columns =["Manufacturer", "iMAGE tYPE", ...])
```

and save it to csv. [Info here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

```
df.to_csv("path/to/file.csv")
```

Comment: I had made a mistake so wasn't getting any outputs. Thanks Alfonso This worked!!

Answer (score 0):

We can't reproduce your results.  Reduce your code to a minimal example or use a debugger to trace where your logic is wrong.  Here's an example based on your update that works:

```
import pandas as pd

Examname = 'Exam1 Exam2 Exam3'.split()
ImageType= 'ImageType1 ImageType2 Imagetype3'.split()
Manufacturer = 'Mfg1 Mfg2 Mfg3'.split()
Series_name = 'Series1 Series2 Series3'.split()
Series_Noise = 'SN1 SN2 SN3'.split()
Slice_thickness = 'thick1 thick2 thick3'.split()
Filter_type = 'ft1 ft2 ft3'.split()
Accessnum = 'anum1 anum2 anum3'.split()
StudyDesc = 'desc1 desc2 desc3'.split()
CTSeriesPath = 'path1 path2 path3'.split()

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(Examname, Manufacturer, ImageType, Series_name,Series_Noise,Slice_thickness,Filter_type,Accessnum,StudyDesc )), columns =["Exam","Manufacturer", "iMAGE tYPE", "Series", "Noise", "Slice Thickness", "Filter Type", "Accession Num", "Study Desc"])
df.to_csv('example.csv',index=False)
```

Also see: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I am sorry. The reason it wasn't working before was because I had SEries_name" but nowhere was it getting output in the programme. Due to that everything was left out from the output file.  I have fixed the code and shown in the updated code in my question. It works